# How to get the autocomplete in angular js?

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs

I have a object which contains name and id.I just want to do the autocomplete based on name.I have tried the code as shown below

```
//Js file
var app=angular.module("myapp",[]);
app.controller("controller",['$scope',function($scope){
    $scope.persons=[
                    {
            Name:"Bhavani",
            Id:67
    },
    {
        Name:"Mamata",
        Id:66
    },
    {
        Name:"Prasanna",
        Id:65
    },
    {
        Name:"Ramya",
        Id:64
    },
    {
        Name:"Navya",
        Id:63
    }
    ];
    $scope.complete=function(){
        $("#autocomp").autocomplete({
            source: $scope.persons.Id
        });
    };
}]);
```

//Html file

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html ng-app="myapp">
<head>
<meta charset="UTF-8">
<title>Auto Complete based on name</title>
<script src="angularfiles/angular.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.8.9/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
<script src="Jsfiles/autocomp.js"></script>
</head>
<body ng-controller="controller">
    <div ng-repeat="p in persons">{{p.Name}}
    </div>
     <div class="ui-widget">
    <input type="text" id="autocomp" ng-keyup="complete()">
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

The above code may have some errors .Its not getting output which i want to have .Can anyone help me out to solve this problem.

Comment: is this what you're trying to use? https://jqueryui.com/autocomplete/

Comment: Try to use **angular-ui-bootstrap typeahead** directive since you are using angularjs. Here's the link: https://angular-ui.github.io/bootstrap/#/typeahead.

Comment: yes but i have a fields in a object name and id..So I am trying to do autocomplete either by name or id @SuperVeetz

Comment: Don't waste time to reinvent the wheel use something like this: http://ghiden.github.io/angucomplete-alt/

Comment: I just only want to do autocomplete based on name from the above code which i have asked

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try like this,
HTML:

```
 <div ng-app = "myapp">
    <div ng-controller="controller">
      <div class="ui-widget">
         <input type="text" id="autocomp" auto-complete>
        </div>
    </div>
  </div>
```

Js:

```
var app = angular.module("myapp",[]);
app.controller("controller",function($scope){
  $scope.availableTags = [
     {
            Name:"Bhavani",
            Id:67
    },
    {
        Name:"Mamata",
        Id:66
    },
    {
        Name:"Prasanna",
        Id:65
    },
    {
        Name:"Ramya",
        Id:64
    },
    {
        Name:"Navya",
        Id:63
    }
    ];

}).directive("autoComplete",function(){
  return function(scope,element,attrs){
    var names =$.map(scope.availableTags,function(value){   return value.Name;          
 });
      element.autocomplete({
      source: names
    });


    };
});
```

Working [jsbin](http://jsbin.com/nukejaguvu/edit?html,js,console,output)

Answer (score 0):

This is how you should use any jQuery API's in an AngularJS project (i believe). Anytime you are doing DOM Manipulation or jQuery things, it should be placed inside the `link: function() {}` via directive.

Probably the main problem with your code was that the `source: $scope.persons.Id` is just a number. The `sourc`e needs to be an array of Strings (at least as per the documentation). So I seperated all the names from your `persons` array and placed them in a new array `peopleNames`

```
    <!doctype html>
    <html lang="en" ng-app="myapp">
    <head>
      <meta charset="utf-8">
      <title>jQuery UI Autocomplete - Default functionality</title>
      <link rel="stylesheet" href="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.4/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css">
      <script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.js"></script>
      <script src="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.4/jquery-ui.js"></script>

      <script src="vendors/angular.min.js"></script>
    </head>
    <body ng-controller="controller">

        <div ng-repeat="p in persons">{{p.Name}}
        </div>

        <div class="ui-widget">
          <input type="text" id="tags" autocomplete-directive>
        </div>

      <script>
        var app = angular.module("myapp",[]);

    app.controller("controller",['$scope',function($scope){
        $scope.persons=[
                        {
                Name:"Bhavani",
                Id:67
        },
        {
            Name:"Mamata",
            Id:66
        },
        {
            Name:"Prasanna",
            Id:65
        },
        {
            Name:"Ramya",
            Id:64
        },
        {
            Name:"Navya",
            Id:63
        }
        ];

      // array of only strings autocomplete
      $scope.peopleNames = [];

      for(var i = 0, j = $scope.persons.length; i < j; i++) {
        $scope.peopleNames.push($scope.persons[i].Name);
      }

    }]);

        app.directive('autocompleteDirective', [function($scope) {
          return {
            link: function(scope, element, attrs) {
              element.autocomplete({
                source: scope.peopleNames
              });
            }
          };
        }]);
      </script>
    </body>

    </html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Thank For every one for suggesting me answer.I have also done in another way .It may help to others.

```
//html file

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html ng-app="myapp">
<head>
<title>Auto Complete based on name</title>
<script src="angularfiles/angular.js"></script>
<script src="angularfiles/angular-animate.js"></script>
<script src="angularfiles/ui-bootstrap-tpls-0.13.4.js"></script>
<script src="angularfiles/bootstrap-theme.css"></script>
<script src="Jsfiles/autocomp.js"></script>
</head>
<body ng-controller="controller">


<div ng-repeat="p in persons">{{p}}</div>
        <div class="ui-widget">
          <input type="text" ng-model="selected" typeahead="p.Name for p in persons | filter:$viewValue">

        </div>
</body>
</html>

//js file

var app = angular.module("myapp",['ui.bootstrap']);

    app.controller("controller",['$scope',function($scope){

        $scope.persons=[
                        {
                Name:"Bhavani",
                Id:67
        },
        {
            Name:"Mamata",
            Id:66
        },
        {
            Name:"Prasanna",
            Id:65
        },
        {
            Name:"Ramya",
            Id:64
        },
        {
            Name:"Navya",
            Id:63
        }
        ];

    }]);
```